# tkinter button press to function call

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

hey guys first post and what not so hi. anyway trying to make a scientific calculator with tkinter and im not very good with it(and python its my second proper assignment). anyway most of the code will probably be wrong but im just trying to take it one step at a time  in particular im concerned about the function add. im calling it via the button however i want to pass the do function a +. this in turn creating an array i can calculate from. it keeps erroring and i dont know how to fix it. its really annoying me now so if someone could help out would be much appreciated

```
from tkinter import*
from operator import*

class App:
    def __init__(self,master):#is the master for the button widgets
        frame=Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.addition = Button(frame, text="+", command=self.add)#when clicked sends a call back for a +
        self.addition.pack()
    def add(Y):
        do("+")
    def do(X):#will hopefully colaborate all of the inputs
        cont, i = True, 0
        store=["+","1","+","2","3","4"]
        for i in range(5):
            X=store[0+i]
            print(store[0+i])
            cont = False
        if cont == False:
            print(eval_binary_expr(*(store[:].split())))
    def get_operator_fn(op):#allows the array to be split to find the operators
        return {
            '+' : add,
            '-' : sub,
            '*' : mul,
            '/' : truediv,
            }[op]
    def eval_binary_expr(op1, num1, op2, num2):
        store[1],store[3] = int(num1), int(num2)
        return get_operator_fn(op2)(num1, num2)


root=Tk()
app=App(root)
root.mainloop()#runs programme
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, every method in a class should take `self` as its first argument. The name `self` is just a convention. It is not a keyword in Python. However, when you call a method such as `obj.add(...)`, the first argument sent to the method is the instance `obj`. It is a convention to call that instance `self` in the method definition. So all your methods need to be modified to include `self` as the first argument:

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):#is the master for the button widgets
        frame=Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.addition = Button(frame, text="+", command=self.add)#when clicked sends a call back for a +
        self.addition.pack()
    def add(self):
        self.do("+")
    def do(self, X):
        ...
```

Note that when you call `self.do("+")`, inside the method `do`, `X` will be bound to `"+"`. Later on in that method I see

```
X=store[0+i]
```

which will rebind `X` to the value `store[i]`. I don't know what you are trying to do here, but be aware that doing so means you've just lost the `"+"` value that was just passed in.

Comment: im trying to add the "+" to the array in sequence so when i have other buttons i can type out the entire equation without having to press enter for each number. as i said though im still just starting out so it would probably be pretty inefficent code(and or doesnt work) but just that top helps out a truck load i couldent figure out why it wouldent work.